# Worst case when finding the maximum depth of binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, binary-tree

This is the pseudo code for finding the maximum depth of binary tree:

```
 maxDepth(Node N)

1. If Nodes is leaf node then return 0

2. Else

     (a) Get the max depth of left subtree recursively  i.e., 

          call maxDepth( N->left-subtree)

     (a) Get the max depth of right subtree recursively  i.e., 

          call maxDepth( N->right-subtree)

     (c) Get the max of max depths of left and right 

          subtrees and add 1 to it for the current node.

         max_depth = max(max dept of left subtree,  
                             max depth of right subtree) 
                             + 1
     (d) Return max_depth
```

I am really confused about thinking worst case for this algorithm.
The complexity of this pseudo code will be O(n). What will be the worst case for this algorithm and why?

Comment: Any case would be the worst case as they are all identical.

Comment: This algorithm will always visit all nodes so the best/average/worst case are all N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out in your question, and others pointed out in comments, the runtime complexity of your algorithm is O(n). It always visits all nodes.

The space complexity, however, is different. The recursion depth depends on the depth of the tree. If the tree is perfectly balanced, then the recursion depth is O(log n). If the tree is degenerate--that is, every node has only one child--then the recursion depth and thus the space complexity is also O(n).

That makes a huge difference. Imagine a tree with 1 million nodes. If it's balanced, the space requirement will be on the order of about 20 stack frames. If the tree is severely unbalanced, the space requirement approaches 1 million stack frames.

The answer to your question, then, is that runtime complexity is O(n), and space complexity is O(log n) in the average case (a reasonably balanced tree), and O(n) in the worst case.